# Получение даты с сервера (ПК)

Tags: java, jsp

Всем привет, есть такая вот ссылка на jsp странице:

`<li><a href="Search?page=1&osdch=${osdch}&osdk=${osdk}&kiz=${kiz}&svi=01.12.2017">Просмотр базы данных Vp44150sql</a></li>`

Как можно получить дату с сервера(ПК) вместо этой `svi=01.12.2017` даты?

Пытаюсь сделать так, в сервлете:

```
long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
String curStringDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(curTime);
request.setAttribute("curStringDate", curStringDate);
```

На jsp:

```
<a href="Search?page=1&osdch=${osdch}&osdk=${osdk}&kiz=${kiz}&s‌​vi=${curStringDate}"‌​>
```

но вот на страничку почему-то не передает, в отладке дата корректная в переменной `curStringDate`

Comment: а зачем вы фронтенд показываете? если время берется из сервлета!

Comment: покажите сервлет, как вы отправляете запрос на jsp

Comment: Укажите, что именно получается на странице. Еще лучше, попробуйте создать [воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), в котором будет только вывод даты на страницу.

Comment: @Виктор вот так  `RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/searchview.jsp");` если я правильно вас понял

Comment: надо дописать forward(request, response);

Comment: @defaultlocale если задавать так `svi=01.12.2017"` то выводятся все записи которые с датой меньшей чем эта, но является максимально близкой, а если так `s‌​vi=${curStringDate}` то ничего белая страница в браузере

Comment: @Виктор если так - `view.forward(request, response);` то уже есть

Comment: тогда выложите достаточно информации для воспроизведения вашей проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем остановился я на подходе с скриплетом:

```
<%long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
String curStringDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(curTime);%>
<a href="Search?page=1&osdch=${osdch}&osdk=${osdk}&kiz=${kiz}&svi=
<%=curStringDate%>">
```